# Why won't the lastest file switch in winscp won't work?

Tags: winscp

I know this will be a question thats answered many times but i just can't get it working.

I need to download some files on a daily basis but only the lastest versions. My script is able to download tthem all but i can't get the -latest switch working. Am I missing something? Many thanx!!

```
option confirm off

open sftp://loginname-sftp:password@10.10.10.10:9998

cd /data/Test
get -latest * -filemask=*>=%TIMESTAMP#dd-mm-yyyy% 
get -latest * /data/Test/*.xml "D:\Test\MH\"
get /data/Test/*.csv "D:\Test\QM\"

exit
```

Comment: We need to know more than *"i can't get the -latest switch working"*. Do you get any error? Or what's wrong? Post session log file.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by using the get -filemask="*>=1D" switch instead of -Latest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).